# no matter how as a conjunction

Tags: grammar

Is it appropriate to omit "they are" in the sentence below? And if yes, why?

> No matter how frequently they are performed, the works of Beethoven always attract a large number of people.

Thank you.

Comment: Syntactically, the (potentially "deleted") subject+verb in *I never buy books, **no matter how** good [**they are**]* is the same as *Please do this if [**it is**] necessary*. It's just that *idiomatically*, there are some exact contexts where we nearly always discard that "optional" subject+verb, and other contexts where we nearly always *keep* them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have no idea what that  means.

Comment: @Lambie: Of course you do [**know what it means**]. Predictably repeated or otherwise unnecessary / obvious words are often "deleted" in such contexts. I assume MichaelHarvey's perfectly correct answer has just been deleted because it's a duplicate. In *Call me day or night, **no matter the time*** we can delete *...no matter **what** the time **is*** in exactly the same way. But in *that* example we could choose to only delete ***is***, but we *can't* choose to delete only ***what*** and keep ***is***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now, you have stated in easier to understand terms. As I have said before, I find your comments hard to understand.

Comment: I'd leave in "they are" here; omitting it might be done in formal English where the writer is trying to be elegant by omitting unnecessary words, but leaving them in makes it easier to understand (especially if you don't know what the person is talking about till they mention Beethoven).